# ASP.NET MVC site has stopped working in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

Totally weird situation.  This web site has been working fine for months.  Don't know when or what happened, but now when I go to www.mysite.com, I just get a blank page.

I put a debug statement in `Global.asax`, which gets hit and leaves a line in a text log file.  But the app never hits the log code in `HomeController` constructor or `HomeController.Index()`.  In fact, I can even navigate to www.mysite.com/oogabooga and it doesn't throw any exceptions about not finding an Oogabooga controller.

In debug mode, everything works fine, but the site simply refuses to run under IIS now.

What could have happened?  How to diagnose?  How to fix?

Comment: Have you checked the event log? Have you checked the current logs in inetpub\wwwroot\logs\? Have you turned on failed request logging?

Comment: Don't forget to turn off custom errors in `Web.config`

Comment: Has the password changed for the account the app pool is running under?

Comment: @Pete - checked windows application log.  Don't have inetpub\wwwroot\logs.  How do you turn on failed request logging?

Comment: @OnResolve - One of my colleagues just informed me that another colleague did put a password on the web site.  Investigating now...

Comment: Go into IIS manager, select the server and then click the "Logging" icon. The directory should be: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles by default. Wherever it is, that's where the log files are for your site. Check those. As for turning on failed request logging, google it. It's multi-step and beyond what I can do in a comment.